# Consecutive object creation using it's predecessors data

Tags: c#, oop, loops, random

I currently have a school assignment, mainly focusing on Object Oriented Programming & using Collections.

I know how most of this is done, however I seem to have hit a snag:
I coded my program so it makes 10 objects, puts them in a `List<T>` & then outputs them to a **ListBox**.

Which works fine, but for some reason, every single object is receiving the same exact values, even though they should be (pseudo)random.

Here's the object's class (named Boom), including it's constructor:

```
public class Boom
{
    public static int aantalBomen = 0;
    public enum boomType { Naald, Loof }

    public boomType BoomType { get; set; }
    public int VolgNr { get; set; }

    private int aantalVogels;
    public int AantalVogels
    {
        get { return aantalVogels; }
        set
        {
            if (value >= 0 && value <= 10)
                aantalVogels = value; 
        }
    }

    public Eekhoorn Eekhoorn { get; set; }

    private int hoogte;
    public int Hoogte
    {
        get { return hoogte; }
        set 
        { 
            if (value >= 5 && value <= 10)
                hoogte = value; 
        }
    }

    public bool eekHoorn = false;

    public Boom()
    {
        aantalBomen++;
        VolgNr = aantalBomen;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Hoogte = rnd.Next(5, 11);
        AantalVogels = rnd.Next(0, 11);
        BoomType = (boomType)Enum.GetValues(typeof(boomType)).GetValue(rnd.Next(0, Enum.GetValues(typeof(boomType)).Length));
    }

    public void MaakEekhoorn()
    {
        Eekhoorn = new Eekhoorn();
        eekHoorn = true;
        aantalVogels = (int)Math.Round((double)(aantalVogels / 2), 0);
    }
}
```

& Here's the loop which creates the 10 objects:

```
public List<Boom> Bomen = new List<Boom>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 10;i++ )
{
    Bomen.Add(new Boom());
}
```

Finally, the code I'm using to test the creation of the objects:

```
for (int i = 0;i<10;i++)
{
    lstBomen.Items.Add("VolgNr: " + bos.Bomen[i].VolgNr.ToString() + " AantalVogels: " + bos.Bomen[i].AantalVogels.ToString() + " BoomType: " +
        bos.Bomen[i].BoomType.ToString() + " Hoogte: " + bos.Bomen[i].Hoogte.ToString());
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why my code keeps generating the exact same values for all 10 objects, resulting in output like this:

[image: Output]

If you need any more info, pertaining to code or anything connected to the program's execution, feel free to ask.

Comment: You are creating a new Random object.  It uses the timetick as a seed.  Since this is a very simple and fast bit of code, you get the same seed every time, hence the same sequence, hence the same values.

Comment: I see, any ideas on how to avoid this? Without getting the same values every time the objects are created (meaning: without the values from 1 batch being the same as the next batch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you always use the same seed value, `Random` will always generate the same sequence. You can pass `i` into the contractor and change it like this:

```
public Boom(int seed)
{
    ...
    Random rnd = new Random(i);
    ...
}
```

To get different numbers each time you run your code:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
public List<Boom> Bomen = new List<Boom>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 10;i++ )
{
    Bomen.Add(new Boom(rnd.Next()));
}
```

Or, just pass `rnd` into the constructor.

Comment: When I try this (by using the value from the object-creation loop `i`) I get the same values every time I try to re-create the objects, is there any way to avoid this, while still getting different trees?

Comment: Create a single Random object and pass that into your objects, that way next will generate different values.

Comment: I'm not sure you know what you mean by that @dbugger, do you mean declaring the Random object outside the constructor, or passing it through to the constructor by means of `public Boom(Random rnd){...}`?

Comment: Create a random object outside the constructor, pass it in.

Comment: That edit works perfectly Nadia, thanks! (You too, thanks @dbugger) :-)